# Interpret coefficient of categorical variable for group with no observation in fixed effect regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interpretation, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I have a hard time interpreting a coefficient from a fixed effect logistic regression, especially in the case where no observation has this value in a given group. Consider this model, where we regress `mpg` by `gear` and fix by `am`.

```r
fe <- feols(mpg ~ factor(gear) | am, data = mtcars)

OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: mpg
Observations: 32 
Fixed-effects: am: 2
Standard-errors: Clustered (am) 
              Estimate Std. Error      t value   Pr(>|t|)    
factor(gear)4 4.943333  1.059e-15 4.670115e+15  < 2.2e-16 ***
factor(gear)5 0.048333  9.330e-16 5.180838e+13 1.2288e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 4.22049     Adj. R2: 0.439567
                Within R2: 0.209315
```

Note however that there are zero observations of gear == 3 in am == 1, and of gear == 5 when am == 0.

```r
> table(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear)
   
     3  4  5
  0 15  4  0
  1  0  8  5
```

So, how is the `gear` coefficient computed in that case, and how should one interpret it? Is it an average of the coefficients from the within-group regressions where we observe at least once the category? Are some groups contributing more to the estimation of the coefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance, as this isn't an answer, but there is no way I could fit it in a comment, or even a series of comments.

I found the documentation for `feols` rather confusing (and the topic of fixed effects is, generally, fraught. The term "fixed" seems to be used different ways by different people (I have seen similar confusion expressed by others).

So, I decided to run this:

```
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ factor(gear) + am, data = mtcars)
```

then `summary(m1)` produced

lm(formula = mpg ~ factor(gear) + am, data = mtcars)

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.3800 -3.3062 -0.7567  3.1575  9.0200 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   16.10667    1.16497  13.826 4.92e-14 ***
factor(gear)4  4.94333    2.53899   1.947   0.0616 .  
factor(gear)5  0.04833    3.61422   0.013   0.9894    
am             5.22500    2.76296   1.891   0.0690 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.512 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4938,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4396 
F-statistic: 9.105 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 0.0002282
```

where the parameter estimates for the levels of gear are the same, but the standard errors are very, very different, and we now have an estimate for am, as well, and an intercept.

But we have the same $R^2$

It's clear that `feols` is using clustered standard errors, but I am not at all sure that that is desirable. I am not sure what else feols is doing.